# Using Parse in RubyMotion app

Tags: parse-platform, rubymotion

I'm having some trouble setting up parse in my RubyMotion app. Does anyone know of a sample project which works with the latest-ish versions of RubyMotion and Parse?

I'm using the `Parsistence` gem. Here is the not working relevant part of my rakefile:

```
app.libs << ['/usr/lib/libz.1.1.3.dylib', '/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib']

app.vendor_project('vendor/Parse.framework', :static, :products => ['Parse'], 
    :headers_dir => 'Headers')

app.frameworks += [
    "Accounts",
    "Social",
    "AdSupport",
    "AudioToolbox",
    "CFNetwork",
    "SystemConfiguration",
    "MobileCoreServices",
    "Security",
    "QuartzCore",
    "StoreKit"]
```

I've copied the `Parse.framework` file into my `vendor` project folder.

This results in the following error:

```
(main)> 2015-05-30 08:21:27.681 myapp[54034:19457576] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '"User" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010417fc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000100e13bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreData                            0x0000000101b9dae5 _PFFastEntityClass + 757
    3   CoreData                            0x0000000101b9d5f7 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _retainedObjectWithID:optionalHandler:withInlineStorage:] + 119
    4   CoreData                            0x0000000101ba46b5 _prepareResultsFromResultSet + 3861
    5   CoreData                            0x0000000101ba1a00 newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT + 3216
    6   CoreData                            0x0000000101b8e33c -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 524
    7   CoreData                            0x0000000101b8ddbb -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 299
    8   CoreData                            0x0000000101c68a6c __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 3356
    9   CoreData                            0x0000000101c71c30 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 192
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000105d0d964 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000105cf6fca _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 76
    12  CoreData                            0x0000000101c63245 _perform + 197
    13  CoreData                            0x0000000101b8da58 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 504
    14  CoreData                            0x0000000101b8c2ca -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 586
    15  lactase2                            0x000000010022d75b __unnamed_156 + 139
    16  lactase2                            0x000000010050346e rb_vm_dispatch + 6270
    17  lactase2                            0x000000010013ec1c vm_dispatch + 1436
    18  lactase2                            0x0000000100237447 rb_scope__array__block__ + 231
    19  lactase2                            0x0000000100504b8f _ZL13vm_block_evalP7RoxorVMP11rb_vm_blockP13objc_selectormiPKm + 1119
    20  lactase2                            0x0000000100503315 rb_vm_dispatch + 5925
    21  lactase2                            0x000000010013ec1c vm_dispatch + 1436
    22  lactase2                            0x000000010022c01e rb_scope__with_error_object:__ + 318
    23  lactase2                            0x00000001005038d9 rb_vm_dispatch + 7401
    24  lactase2                            0x000000010013ec1c vm_dispatch + 1436
    25  lactase2                            0x0000000100237314 rb_scope__array__ + 356
    26  lactase2                            0x00000001005038d9 rb_vm_dispatch + 7401
    27  lactase2                            0x000000010013ec1c vm_dispatch + 1436
    28  lactase2                            0x00000001003e4015 rb_scope__create_standard_user__ + 213
    29  lactase2                            0x00000001005038d9 rb_vm_dispatch + 7401
    30  lactase2                            0x000000010013ec1c vm_dispatch + 1436
    31  lactase2                            0x00000001003e38c9 rb_scope__on_load:__ + 217
    32  lactase2                            0x00000001005038d9 rb_vm_dispatch + 7401
    33  lactase2                            0x000000010013ec1c vm_dispatch + 1436
    34  lactase2                            0x000000010033703a rb_scope__application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:__ + 202
    35  lactase2                            0x000000010033723d __unnamed_34 + 61
    36  UIKit                               0x0000000102ca8788 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 240
    37  UIKit                               0x0000000102ca9397 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2540
    38  UIKit                               0x0000000102cac1de -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349
    39  UIKit                               0x0000000102cab0d5 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    40  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010724d5e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001040b341c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001040a9165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001040a8f25 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    44  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001040a8366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    45  UIKit                               0x0000000102caab42 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    46  UIKit                               0x0000000102cad900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    47  lactase2                            0x000000010014707f main + 111
    48  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000105d3d145 start + 1
    49  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I have a `User` model which is used for CoreData stuff:

```
class User < CDQManagedObject
end
```

I'm not really sure what causes the error and am thankful for any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Renaming the `User` class was the solution. Of course this is no real solution, but it solves the problem.